# gcloud sql databases list operation consistently fails for certain cloud SQL instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-shell

I running the following gcloud command, where myinstance1 is a MySQL instance.

```
gcloud sql databases list --instance=myinstance1 --format="value(name)"
```

However I consistently get one of the following two  errors , is this an issue with gcloud (as this is still in beta) or with the MySQL instances ?

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.databases.list) HTTPError 503: Service temporarily unavailable. This is most likely a transient error. Please retry.

ERROR: (gcloud.sql.databases.list) HTTPError 400: This operation isn"t valid for this instance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that these instances that were failing for the API call were in a stopped state.